# Searching for all integers that occure twice in a vector

Tags: c, vector, comparison

I got the task in university to realize an input of a maximum of 10 integers, which shall be stored in a one dimensional vector. Afterwards, every integer of the vector needs to be displayed on the display (via printf).

However, I don't know how to check the vector for each number. I thought something along the lines of letting the pointer of the vector run from 0 to 9 and comparing the value of each element with all elements again, but I am sure there is a much smarter way.  I don't in any case know how to code this idea since I am new to C.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int vector[10];
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;

    printf("Please input 10 integers.\n\n");

    while (a <= 10);    
    {
        for (scanf_s("%lf", &vektor[a]) == 0)
            {
                printf("This is not an integer. Please try again.\n");
                fflush(stdin);
            }
        a++;
    }

    for (b <= 10);
        {
            if (vector[b] != vector[c]);
                {
                    printf("&d", vector[b]);
                    c++;
                }
            b++;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is the input constricted? like numbers 0-100? If so you can use an aux array[100] and if not a double for loop will do

Comment: @H.cohen No. Only integers. (32 bit)

Comment: For so few numbers to test, an approach of the general kind you describe should be fine.  Alternatively, however, you could sort the input, thereby leaving all duplicate elements in consecutive locations.  There are may be other viable alternatives, too, depending on the constraints on your input.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for confirming that. However I am more concerned with how to actually code this into a running program. As I said this is about my 10. programm ever and the first 9 I didnt even program myself rather than copying pieces from this forum xD

Can I run the pointer of the vector with a variable? Or is there an operation that does this for me?

Comment: I'm sorry, @Lukas, but "How do I write this program?" is too broad a question.  Since this is an exercise for a formal class, I suggest you start by reviewing the course materials and your lecture notes.  Then try something.  Working out solutions to the exercises is one of the more important ways that you will learn the course material.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I already wrote a program trying that. However I am to inexperienced with the syntax. I dont know how to express this condition.

I tried `while (a <= 10); 
 {
  for (scanf_s("%lf", &vektor[a]) == 0)
   {
    printf("Eingabe ungueltig, neue Eingabe erforderlich.\n");
    fflush(stdin);
   }
  a++;
 }`


This is for the input of the 10 integers

Comment: @LukasLanger, if you have a program you would like us to consider then please edit it into the question, and pose a specific question about it. But note, however, that what you've just presented in your comment appears to do nothing more than read the input.  We're willing to help -- to some extent -- but we're looking for a good-faith effort at solving the problem yourself.  If you really haven't a clue how to start then we're probably not the resource you want.  In that case, consider seeking help from your instructor, a teaching assistant, or a classmate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok, I am sorry. Let me reprhase my question in addition to my very first code I added to the question.

Is there an operator that searches in a vector (such as searchvector[a] for example) and if there is none is my method apart from some syntax errors on the right path? Is this a viable means of comparison in C?

Comment: 1) `vektor[]` is not define/declare anywhere.  Post true code. 2) `scanf_s("%lf", &vektor[a])` expects `vektor[a]` to be a `double`, not `int`.

Comment: @chux Actually vektor[a] is vector[a] but I quickly translated the program from german to english since we say vektor instead of vector and also the printf parts were in German. Therefore vektor is declared in the very first line of the main function. So by changing the input to a double the return value of the scanf_s should be true and the input is saved in the vector?

But again I declared ` int vector[10]` . Why should the program expect a double?

Comment: @LukasLanger "return value of the scanf_s should be true" --> The return value will be 1 of 3 things: `EOF, 0, 1`.  It will be 1 when text input was successfully converted to a `double`.  Suggest you edit and post true compilable code and clearly reword post.  Do not use "integer" when `double` is being read or do not use `double` if `int`s are being read.  This will add clarity to your goal.

Comment: `while (a <= 10);` --> infinite loop. Note the `;` at the end is the _body_ of the loop.  This points out a key failing here - you are not enabling all compiler warnings (or using a weak compiler). A good compiler would have warned of that mistake.   **Save time**  enable all warnings, fix problems and then re-post _true_  code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems, some syntactic and some semantic.  Your compiler will help with many of the former kind, such as

- misspelling of variable name `vector` in one place (though perhaps this was a missed after-the-fact edit), and
- incorrect syntax for a `for` loop

Some compilers will notice that your `scanf` format is mismatched with the corresponding argument.  Also, you might even get a warning that clues you in to the semicolons that are erroneously placed between your loop headers and their intended bodies.  I don't know any compiler that would warn you that bad input will cause your input loop to spin indefinitely, however.

But I guess the most significant issue is that the details of your approach to printing only non-duplicate elements simply will not serve.  For this purpose, I recommend figuring out how to describe *in words* how the computer (or a person) should solve the problem before trying to write C code to implement it.  These are really two different exercises, especially for someone whose familiarity with C is limited.  You can reason about the prose description without being bogged down and distracted by C syntax.

For example, here are some words that might suit:

1. Consider each element, E, of the array in turn, from first to last.
2. Check all the elements preceding E in the array for one that contains the same value.
3. If none of the elements before E contains the same value as E then E contains the first appearance of its value, so print it.  Otherwise, E's value was already printed when some previous element was processed, so do not print it again.
4. Consider the next E, if any (go back to step 1).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I use Visual Studio and I encountered the problems you and @chux described but couldnt find the problem with the loops head. I found that I get quite confused with the ` ; ` but I guess this is something I have to find out myself. I will try to code this into a working program tomorrow. But so far thanks for you patience.